# IE11 pasting string of text into the textbox

Tags: string, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, textfield, microsoft-edge

Any idea why IE11 won't allow me to paste the block of strings in a text box on the page form? I have tried with Edge and Chrome and no problem there.

For example, if I copy a number of strings formatted as a column from a text file or Excel and try to paste it to the Text field on the form in IE11, only the first string is being pasted. On the other hand, all strings are being pasted in Edge or Chrome.

I'm trying to copy this text:

[image]

And when is pasted into IE11 I'm ending up with this:

[image]

But when I paste it in the Edge or Chrome I'm getting  this:

[image]

Any idea if there are some settings in IE11 which must be changed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue in the Internet Explorer browser.

When you try to copy the column from Excel then it contains newline characters in it. Input type text does not support the newline characters and the IE browser removes it. Because of this reason, the full text does not get parsed and it only pastes the first string.

There are some workarounds available to overcome this issue for the IE browser.

1. You can try to use **Textarea** instead of **Input textbox**.
2. You can try to use some JS/ Jquery code to replace all of the newline characters with spaces.

Example:

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (window.clipboardData) {
        $('#txt1').bind('paste', function (e) {
            var clipped = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            clipped = clipped.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "); //replace newlines with spaces
            $(this).val(clipped);
            return false; //cancel the pasting event
        });
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<label for="txt1">Enter text:</label>
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" style="width:200px"><br><br>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

References:

1. [Allow pasting multiple lines in IE textbox](https://www.brandonpugh.com/blog/2011/10/allow-pasting-multiple-lines-in-ie-textbox/)
2. [Copy-Paste from MS Excel fails with IE but works with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009447/10309381)

Comment: The thing is that I don't control the website we are using. I was hoping there will be some switch in the browsers I can use. That's a lot for suggestions and the code sample.

Comment: This is by design and there is no option available to change this behavior. Thanks for your understanding.